# Shortest possible string of functions to give $4x+22$ and $4x+3$

Tags: problem-solving

I want to check if my solution to a) iii) and b) iii) are correct.

For a) iii) I got AAMAMA and for b) iii) I got MAMMSD or MMAMAD

I'm not sure if they are the shortest; I just suspect they are because I haven't found any smaller ones.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you do any of it?  Do you understand the MMA examples?

Comment: @RossMillikan For a) iii) I got AAMAMA and for b) iii) I got MAMMSD or MMAMAD. I'm not sure if they are the shortest; I just suspect they are because I haven't found any smaller ones. I can do the preceding parts of the question and I understand the MMA examples. Forgive me for copying and pasting from the question.

Comment: You should be able to justify the ones you found are shortest.  For a)iii, note you must have two Ms to get the 4x, then the As before both Ms contribute 8 and the one between the Ms contributes 4.  For b)iii you must have a D to get the constant to be odd, so you need three Ms to get the 4x.